# How can I print a map with my GPS track?

Tags: gps, maps, navigation

I have tracks from a bike tour in GPX format. Is there an easy way to create printable topo maps with these tracks? Waypoints should be visible and labelled as well.

QGIS might be an option, but it's very technical and the print features are limited. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not specifically about bicycles.  Suggest asking on GIS. SE

Comment: Can you load them into Strava ?

Comment: @mattnz: there are `maps` and `navigation` tags, and I see similar questions here already.

@Criggie: does Strava have a print feature?

Comment: @ValiaAlexopoulos Yes you can print planned routes - it produces a page like this link  -
 let me know if it doesn't work for you and I'll screenshot it 
  https://www.strava.com/routes/9344148/cue_sheet
   If you have a track you've followed, then that will be plotted on a google-style map and you can print that if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie, this is a start. The usefulness of the map is limited though, it's small and not very printable.

Comment: @ValiaAlexopoulos Oh oh I'm running Chrome with a bolt-on extension called StravistiX which gives heaps more useful functions, like a proper google map you can scroll around.  Printing seems to be a bit limited but that's why you have a phone/device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Inkatlas](https://inkatlas.com) lets you create printable PDF maps with GPS tracks and waypoints (on multiple pages if needed). You can select a map style with terrain. Smaller PDFs (6 pages or fewer) are free.

Full disclosure: this is my project.

Comment: I've just tried this for an outline map of a 100km ride I'm booked onto and I'm very pleased with the result (as 4A4, so free).  The free output is actually enough to really put it to the test, which would encourage me to  come back for longer routes